What is the name of the cartoon that was referred in The Dictator (2012)?
In the Nuclear-Nadal scene, Both Aladeen and Nadal argue about the nuclear missile being pointy. In that argument, Aladeen refers to a cartoon (as per him they are research films) where the missiles stick to the ground and then explode while the victims possesses a frown face.
Could anyone let me know the episode title and cartoon name? (I did search on Google though but couldn't find it.)




I may be wrong, but I always thought that was sort of a generalization.  Like, you can see that type of thing happen in a Tom & Jerry cartoon, but it never really happened.  I don't think he's referring to a specific cartoon there.

He's not referencing a specific cartoon, but rather the trope of cartoon missiles or rockets being pointy a lot of the time, characters simply possessing sooty faces after encountering them, and occasionally becoming angels with harps. These happen a lot in cartoons, and the only specific ones mentioned in that conversation are Popeye (by name) and this:

Nadal: In this film (just one question), was there a duck who, when this explosion happens, his bill goes around to the back of his head and then in order to talk, he has to put it back this way?
Aladeen: There was somebody who suffered a deformity like that.

This is most likely Daffy Duck. Similar injuries to the one depicted here happen to him quite often, most famously in the classic 'Hunting Trilogy' from 1951-3 (see the compilation below) and more specifically the 2nd cartoon in that trilogy, Rabbit Seasoning. The only classic Looney Tunes cartoon that comes to mind with Daffy and pointy missiles is Duck Dodgers in the 24½th Century from 1953, and while he is shot in the face there, his bill does not spin around IIRC.




Jesus, when you watch it like this it's hard to believe this was conventional kids' programming. Shooting a talking creature in the head multiple times with a shotgun? Not for the faint of heart!

The exact description of this event is seen on: Bugs Bunny - Duck! Rabbit, Duck!
@ 2:55 http://dai.ly/x2of854

True, but this also happens midway through Rabbit Seasoning.

But not exactly as described.

Pretty exactly, I watched it just now. It's around 02:45. I mentioned it in my answer because his bill goes to the back of his head in that one, like Nadal describes. In  Duck! Rabbit, Duck!, it goes sideways. [Though I did mention the entire trilogy, just in case. It's required viewing for cartoon lovers :)]

But it is still not the exact event described as it goes to the top and side of his head and doesn't spin, that is why I say I say that is the true and only one there boy.

No one in The Dictator sthaid it sthpins, though.
